# When pulling column names from table in SQL, lots of extra fields are pulled

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tkinter, mysql-connector

I am building a simple GUI in python to allow a user to insert and delete data from tables in a MySQL database. For all tables but one, the information is pulled correctly and only the corresponding field names are pulled. However, when I query the last table in the database (in this case 'user'), a plethora of extra fields are pulled.

The query I am using is as follows:

```
"select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'user';"
```

These are the returned column_names:

```
[('date_joined',), ('email',), ('password',), ('phone',), ('user_id',), ('username',), ('account_locked',), ('Alter_priv',), ('Alter_routine_priv',), ('authentication_string',), ('Create_priv',), ('Create_role_priv',), ('Create_routine_priv',), ('Create_tablespace_priv',), ('Create_tmp_table_priv',), ('Create_user_priv',), ('Create_view_priv',), ('Delete_priv',), ('Drop_priv',), ('Drop_role_priv',), ('Event_priv',), ('Execute_priv',), ('File_priv',), ('Grant_priv',), ('Host',), ('Index_priv',), ('Insert_priv',), ('Lock_tables_priv',), ('max_connections',), ('max_questions',), ('max_updates',), ('max_user_connections',), ('password_expired',), ('password_last_changed',), ('password_lifetime',), ('Password_require_current',), ('Password_reuse_history',), ('Password_reuse_time',), ('plugin',), ('Process_priv',), ('References_priv',), ('Reload_priv',), ('Repl_client_priv',), ('Repl_slave_priv',), ('Select_priv',), ('Show_db_priv',), ('Show_view_priv',), ('Shutdown_priv',), ('ssl_cipher',), ('ssl_type',), ('Super_priv',), ('Trigger_priv',), ('Update_priv',), ('User',), ('User_attributes',), ('x509_issuer',), ('x509_subject',)]
```

The correct list should be:

```
[('date_joined',), ('email',), ('password',), ('phone',), ('user_id',), ('username',)]
```

Am I missing something that is having this pull all these extra details?

Comment: Are you picking up the user table inside the mysql schema? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html#grant-tables-user-db You can add `AND table_schema = 'XXX'` to limit it to the schema you're interested in.

Comment: @NickODell seems to be working now. Oddly enough I tried that earlier and it did not work, but now it is. May have missed something originally. thank you